# Returning this from a constructor function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a constructor function in JavaScript I want to be able to explicitly return something so that everything is clear when working in a team.

I read that if you use a function as a constructor in JS that if you return anything then using the new keyword will have been a wasted effort. But I am wondering if you can return `this` from the constructor function and be safe, for example:

```
function MyConstructor(val){

      this.val = val;
      return this;   //attention here

}

var example = new MyConstructor(val);
```

Does this yield the desired behavior?

Comment: I don't feel this is a good idea. A constructor function is unique to other functions for a reason. If you end up explicitly returning from a constructor function then your using parasitic inheritance and in essence not using a constructor function but a regular function. Why the need to confuse the two and confuse future developers by breaking de facto conventions?

Comment: To be frank, your assuming you know better then others on your team. If I was on your team I would be really confused why `return this` was necessary and attempt to remove the redundant and confusing statement. I apologize if that seemed mean but I personally believe in readability and part of readability is familiarity. If there isn't a really good reason to change well known patterns it is better not to. If you do explicitly state the change with comments. This is all assuming your entire team hasn't asked for the `return this` pattern which in case forget everything I've said.

Comment: IMO there needs to be some metadata in some form to mark the function as a constructor function one of them could be to explicitly return this, in some form or another :)

Comment: If you want consistent behavior regardless of whether the `new` keyword is used, don't use `this` but rather some other variable and return that, e.g. `var self = {}; ... return self`

Comment: it might hv to be var self= this; for protypical inheritance to work as expected.

Comment: @AlexMills that meta data your talking about is usually accomplished using a capital letter in the name. `function functionNamesLikeThis()` is just a function, `function ClassNamesLikeThis()` is a constructor. This is no different then the convention of an underscore for private properties `this.publicProperty` vs `this._privateProperty`. Many style guides suggest that like Google's https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Naming#Naming

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the normal behavior of JavaScript. If you do not return anything from a constructor function, it will work as expected (of course).

Hence

```
var Dog = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
};

var alice = new Dog('Alice');
```

results in a new object whose `name` property is set to `Alice`.

Now what happens if you try to override the implicit `return` statement of the constructor function by explicitly calling it?

Let's introduce a `return` statement that returns something else:

```
var Dog = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
  return 23;
};

var alice = new Dog('Alice');
```

Which value is `alice` now? Probably, you'd expect that it's `23`, but actually it isn't. It still is an object with a `name` property set to `Alice`.

The problem here is that JavaScript is smarter than you: It sees your `return`, but realizes that the type of the thing you want to return does not match the fact that the function has been called using `new`. Hence the `return` is ignored.

Now what if we try to get smarter than JavaScript and return something whose type matches, i.e. an object?

```
var Dog = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
  return { foo: 'bar' };
};

var alice = new Dog('Alice');
```

In this case, JavaScript thinks that you have a good reason to override the implicit `return` and actually uses yours. This means that `alice` now points to an object with a `foo` property which is set to `'bar'`.

So, to cut a long story short: If you explicitly call

```
return this;
```

you end up with the last case. You override the object that is implicitly being returned. But since the one you return is actually the same as the one that would have been returned implicitly, there is no difference.

So: Yes, it is the same, but the call to `return this;` is not required.

Some developers use this behavior to trick JavaScript into always returning a new object, no matter whether you call the constructor function with or without `new`:

```
var Dog = function (name) {
  return {
    name: name
  };
};

var alice1 = new Dog('Alice');
var alice2 = Dog('Alice');
```

Both calls result in a new object with a `name` property set to `Alice`, but there are some differences to the previous examples:

- Both objects are just object literals, whose `constructor` property is not set to `Dog`, neither they use the expected prototype chain.
- In the case *with* `new` actually two objects are being created: One by `new`, the other by you using the object literal syntax. This means more work for the garbage collector.

Hence, I think, that you should avoid this technique, and either use constructors correctly or stick to factory functions.

This is the same effect that was made use of in [@maboiteaspam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30419791/1333873):

```
function DHT (opts) {
  var self = this
  if (!(self instanceof DHT)) return new DHT(opts)
  // ctor body
}
```

If you call this function with `new`, `this` is set to an object whose `constructor` property points to the `DHT` function. Hence `self instanceof DHT` returns true and the actual constructor is run.

If you call this function without `new`, the `if` statement detects this and runs it with `new` for you automatically (which is at least better than the solution described above, where you end up with two disadvantages).

Please note that in strict mode it is not allowed to access `this` from a function that is not called on an object, hence calling a constructor function without the `new` keyword would result in an error as soon as you tried to access `this`.

Comment: Of all the options you mentioned, strict mode seems to be the simplest way to prevent misuse... +1

Answer (score 2):

You can return `this` in your constructor, but will have the same effect as not returning anything.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> When the code `new Foo(...)` is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from `Foo.prototype`.
> 2. The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments and
>      this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is equivalent to new
>      `Foo()`, i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is called without
>      arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the
>      result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function
>      doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is
>      used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they
>      can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object
>      creation process.)

Answer (score 2):

A different approach could be :

```
function DHT (opts) {
  var self = this
  if (!(self instanceof DHT)) return new DHT(opts)
  // ctor body
}
```

Credits goes to https://github.com/feross/bittorrent-dht/blob/master/client.js

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is naming conventions not language features. The problem with that approach is that you obfuscating the intent. Imagine you had this coding style as part of your team. If I was on it I would probably have the following dialog in my head several times a day while working on the code:

```
var foo - foobar(); // Um wait is this a constructor or a function?
// I guess I'll have to look it up:
function foobar() {
  // skip a bunch of code.
  return this;
}
// Huh? Why do I need to return this? And what is this supposed to refer to?
// Do I need to always provide a context when calling this function?
// Oh wait that some weird convention I was told about during employee initiation.
// Guess I have to deal with this for now and note to self:
//   Brush up my resume, gonna need it soon.
var foo = new foobar();
```

So the moral is that at the time of using a function the programmer has no information how that function is meant to be called.

A better method would be to use naming conventions in that every function that starts with a capital letter is a constructor while lowercase is just a normal function.

This convention is widely known and is used on many teams:

```
function FooBar() {}

var foo = new FooBar(); // Capital letter need to use new
var bar = fooBar(); // lowercase means a normal function.
```

Comment: +1. Naming conventions can indeed be very helpful here...I posted some other suggestions on naming conventions in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Actually, in strict mode, `this` is undefined, so the programmer who forgot to use `this` would immediately get an error - so that would be the quickest way for them to notice their mistake. So simply using strict mode might be the best solution:

```
"use strict";
function MyConstructor(val){
    this.val = val;
}
```

(Or you could put "use strict" inside the function if you have other code in the same script that you don't want to run in strict mode.)

---

Here's an example that shows in more detail how you could make it work the same regardless of whether or not `new` is used:

```
function MyConstructor(val) {
    var self = Object.create(MyConstructor.prototype);
    self.constructor = MyConstructor;
    self.val = val;
    return self;
}

var example = new MyConstructor(val);
var example2 = MyConstructor(val); //same result
```

Of course, that's a little verbose, so in practice it would probably be simpler to use the approach in @maboiteaspam's answer.

Personally I don't worry about this; if a programmer fails to use the `new` keyword, they should notice the mistake since they would just get the `window` object back (or null if in strict mode) instead of a new object instance.

But if you prefer a style that doesn't require the use of the `new` keyword at all, then you could consider using a library intended for more prototypal usage, e.g.:

- https://github.com/Raynos/pd
- https://github.com/Gozala/selfish

Or you could just use a naming convention that makes the intended usage more clear, as @Sukima suggested. You could prefix your maker functions with "make" or "create" to make it more clear, e.g. `makeUser()` or `createUser()`. Or to use the style from the "selfish" library above, `User.new()`.