# JS Power Constructor and instanceof without new

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, new-operator

To quote [this guy](https://youtu.be/DwYPG6vreJg?t=27m13s) we can use a power constructor which has the form

```
function constructor() {
    var that = {};
    that.data = true;
    that.method = function () {};
    return that;
}
```

To create objects that will behave correctly with or without the `new` keyword.

My question is how do we wire up the intanceof operator to work with power constructors? I think it has something to do with the object.prototype.constructor attribute but I'm not sure how to edit it in the scope of the constructor function.

```
constructor() instanceof constructor // false but I want it to be true
new constructor() instanceof constructor // true
```

Comment: There's a simpler approach: simply add "use strict" to the top of your file or the beginning of your constructor function. That will ensure that `this` is undefined if the programmer forgets to use the `new` keyword.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419297/returning-this-from-a-constructor-function-in-js

Comment: @MattBrowne I'm trying to avoid `new` its a school of thought in js to not use it.

Comment: @TomDDD: why that? At least this makes clear what you are doing, i.e. creating an new instance of something

Comment: @MattBrowne `new` can be seen as bad practice. It doesn't get the prototype chain right. You have to manually set it later. There is a large camp of js users who omit it from the language.

Comment: "It doesn't get the prototype chain right." - ??? - you have already shown that the "power constructor" does not get it right instead, and you need boilerplate to work around it. So why exactly not using "new"?

Comment: @TomDDD There is nothing wrong with using `new`, it's not bad practice.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the link I put in the question is a video to Douglas Crockford one of the most influential people in the javascript community for style and use of the language. He states maybe 10 seconds later that he only uses new in one place in javascript. as a wrapper to make the object function which gets the proto chain right and allows for optional new keyword for all other object creation.

Comment: Douglas used to be influential, but has fallen behind the times. He wrote one good book once and has been doling out more and more radically bad advice since.

Comment: @Domenic I happen to like that book though. I learned a lot through it. Is it really a sin to think of new as a bad part?

Comment: Well, he has made a lot of great contributions to the language, but he is not a god ... not everything he says is therefore the answer to everything, and especially in this case I would object. "new" is nothing to avoid, imho the exact opposite is true, as your example proves. Again: if I see something like var bla = fn(), I would not expect that I get an instance. If I use "new" I know.

Comment: His advice to think in terms of prototypal inheritance rather than the classical inheritance of class-based languages is good advice, because then your thinking is more aligned with Javascript's prototypal OO model. However, it's possible to think in prototypes rather than classes and still use the `new` keyword, you just need to understand it.

Comment: To really understand prototypes, check out the "Self" language which heavily influenced JS's object model: http://www.selflanguage.org/_static/published/organizing-programs.pdf

Comment: @TomDDD It's a good book. But if you want to write non-idiomatic code by swearing off a large part of the language (i.e. the entire object allocation and functions-as-constructors infrastructure) then you're just going to cause yourself trouble. Maybe not a sin, but certainly unpleasant for anyone trying to read or maintain your code in the future.

Comment: Also, while I prefer just using `new`, if you're going to go down the road of programming without it, you might find this chapter of this book useful: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes

Comment: @MattBrowne Thanks I'll checkout that book

Comment: ... and, take a look at this for more advantages when using "new": http://jsperf.com/power-constructors-vs-new-keyword-for-object-instances In case of FF, "power constructors" are 99%(!!!) slower, and AFAIK they also use more memory. So, does this "power constructor" still sound like a "power constructor" now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to buy into the school of thought in JS that you should not use `new`, then you are opting out of a lot of the language features, including `instanceof`.

`instanceof` goes hand in hand with the JavaScript function-as-constructor + prototypal inheritance paradigm. `x instanceof C` specifically looks at `C.prototype`, and compares it with x's prototype chain (see [OrdinaryHasInstance](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ordinaryhasinstance) algorithm). The `C.prototype` lookup is designed to work with the `new` operator, which, when applied to any function `F`, will create a new object with `F.prototype` in its prototype chain, on which the constructor `F` will run (with `this` set to that newly-allocated object).

"Power constructors" are just functions that return objects, and don't work with the normal language machinery (including ES2015 classes). Trying to use `instanceof` with them is contradictory: if you want to swear off `new`, you should swear off `instanceof` as well.

Any tricks you do to make `instanceof` work, like those in Matt Browne's answer, will end up essentially re-creating the entire infrastructure that `new` already provides. (See [a similar conversation I've had previously](https://blog.domenic.me/the-revealing-constructor-pattern/#comment-2035370013).)

Comment: ...and you could use `isPrototypeOf()` instead of `instanceof` as I mentioned in my answer. I don't agree with Crockford that `new` needs to be avoided, but if you do want to avoid it then `isPrototypeOf()` is a viable alternative, so long as you're aware that you can't rely on `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construction

```
function constructor() {
    if (!(this instanceof constructor))
        return new constructor();
    this.data = true;
    this.method = function () { };
}
```

This construction you can find in [Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/lib) native modules

Example:

```
function Hash(algorithm, options) {
    if (!(this instanceof Hash))
        return new Hash(algorithm, options);
    this._handle = new binding.Hash(algorithm);
    LazyTransform.call(this, options);
}
```

Comment: This is not a power constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I personally prefer to just use strict mode to ensure that the programmer doesn't forget to use the `new` keyword. But here's another way of doing this, without using the `new` keyword at all:

```
function demo() {
    var that = Object.create(demo.prototype);
    that.data = true;
    that.method = function () {};
    return that;
}

var d = demo();
d instanceof demo // true
```

And here's an alternative approach that also avoids the use of `new`:

```
var demo = {
    init: function() {
        this.data = true;
    },
    method: function() {}
}
var d = Object.create(demo);
d.init();

demo.isPrototypeOf(d) // true
```